# execute stored procedure with dbslim with Fitnesse (Selenium,Xebium)

Tags: sql-server, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

https://github.com/markfink/dbslim

I'd like to execute the stored procedures with DbSlim using Fitnesse (Selenium, Xebium)

now what I tried to do is:

```
!define dbQuerySelectCustomerbalance (
execute dbo.uspLogError
)

| script | Db Slim Select Query | !-${dbQuerySelectCustomerbalance}-! |
```

which gives a green indicator,
however Microsoft SQL Server profiler gives no actions/logging...

so what i'd like to know is: is it possible to use dbslim for executing stored procedures, 
if yes
what is the correct way to do it?

By the way, the connection to the Database i've on 1 page, and on the query page i included the connection to the database. (is that ok?)

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `!- ... -!`. It is used to escape wikified words. But in this case you want it to be translated to the actual query.

```
!define dbQuerySelectCustomerbalance ( execute dbo.uspLogError )

| script | Db Slim Select Query | ${dbQuerySelectCustomerbalance} |
| show | data by column index | 1 | and row index | 1 |
```

You can add in the last line which outputing the first column of the first row  for testing purpose if your SP is returning some result (or you can create one simple SP just to test this out)

Specifying the connection anywhere before this block will be fine, be it on the same page or in an SetUp/SuiteSetUp/normal page included/executed before.